# Concatenate a csv file in archive

Tags: linux, csv, unzip, zcat

I stumble with a problem.

I need to read a .csv table in an archive without extracting it.
When I try to do that, I face metadata bits in the beginning of the file.

```
➜  dir ls
people-10000.tar.gz

➜  dir zcat people-10000.tar.gz | head -2
**people-10000.csv0000644000000000000000000431074114440102423012217 0ustar  rootrootIndex**,User Id,First Name,Last Name,Sex,Email,Phone,Date of birth,Job Title
1,5f10e9D33fC5f2b,Sara,Mcguire,Female,tsharp@example.net,(971)643-6089x9160,1921-08-17,"Editor, commissioning"
```

Is it possible to do that?

I tried `unzip -p`, but have nothing.

```
➜  dir unzip -p people-10000.tar.gz
[people-10000.tar.gz]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.
```

Either this file is not
a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
the last disk(s) of this archive.

Comment: That metadata is the tar header.

Comment: `unzip` is for zip archives, not tar archives.

Comment: gz is not zip. zip is not gz.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `--to-stdout` (or `-O`) option to send the extracted file to stdout rather than creating a file.

```
tar -x -f people-10000.tar.gz --to-stdout -z filename.csv | head -2
```

Replace `filename.csv` with the actual name of the CSV file in the archive.